# В чем ошибка в коде?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, json, php

Почему при таком коде ничего не происходит? В чем ошибка?
Простой рабочий пример (jquery autocomplete и jsonp) + php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ы</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search").keyup(function(){
                $("#search").autocomplete({
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                      alert(1)
                    },
                    delay:10,
                    minChars:1,
                    maxItemsToShow:10
                });
        });
     });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form action=""><input type="search" id="search"> <input type="submit"></form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В консоли тишина? Onclick и подобное работает?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

У вас скрипт `jquery.autocomplete.js` лежит в той же папке, где и html-страница?

Comment: *ui* нужно подключить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) оно является плагином ,или как еще виджетом, который без ядра *jQuery* и *jQueryUI* не будет работать.

[Посмотрите какие](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) библиотеки должны быть подключены, чтоб нормально фукционировал.

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю принципа вашей инициализации скрипта. Зачем вы вешаете инициализацию на $("#search").keyup()? Человек наберет букву, после чего будет происходить инициализация плагина который будет ожидать ввод буквы, а ввод буквы соответственно заново инициализировать плагин?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    ...
  });
});
```

Плюс уточните какой именно Автокомплит вы пытаетесь использовать. Есть плагин который создавался изначально. Есть виджет (взяли плагин и внедрили его в jquery UI с изменением параметров вызова). В зависимости от того какой у вас аутокомплит их надо по разному подключать и инициализировать.